# Proving compactness of an operator $(Kf)(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}k(t+s)f(s)ds$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I was trying to prove the compactness of the following operator:
$K:L_2([0,\infty))\to L_2([0,\infty))$

$(Kf)(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty}k(t+s)f(s)ds$, given that the function $k$ is continous, and $\int_{0}^{\infty} |k(s)|ds < \infty$.

My first intuition was to think how this operator would look like if the question was about $\ell_2$. I was thinking of the function $k$ as a sequence $k_n$ which converges to zero and acts on $e_i$ as follows:
$Ae_i = S_l^{i}(k_n)$. where $S_l$ is a left shift.
It might sound a bit strange and i couldn't actually convert the problem to $\ell_2$.

Then i thought maybe it would be better to take $K_n$ - compact operators and to show that $K$ is a limit of those. (where each $K_n$ is anintegral from $[0,n]$), anyway, perhaps there's a more elegant solution to this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Can you do it if you assume $k$ is an infinitely differentiable compactly-supported function?

Comment: @TrialAndError if i know it's compactly supported, can i say say then that $k(s,t)=k(t+s) \in L_2([0,\infty)^2)$ and therefore it's a hilbert-schmidt integral operator?

Comment: Is $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}|k(s,t)|^2ds dt < \infty$ in that case?

Comment: @TrialAndError I might be missing something but it seems to me that it if $k(s)$ is compactly bounded and continuous then $k(s,t)$ also is and therefore $|k|^2$ is integrable as a product of integrable fuctions.

Comment: You have $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}|k(s,t)|^2dsdt = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{t}^{\infty}|k(u)|^2dudt$ and the inner integral is $0$ for large $t$. I can't see anything that goes wrong. The norm of $K$ is bounded by $\|k\|_{L^1}$. So if you can approximate $k$ in the $L^1$ norm with a compactly supported function ...

Comment: @TrialAndError then i can say that $k(s,t)\in L_2$ as i take $k_n = k \cdot \mathbb{1}|_{[0,n]}$ and $n\to \infty$ because i'm always bounded by the norm of $k$ in $L^1$?

Comment: $\|K-K_n\|_{\mathscr{L}(L^2[0,\infty))} \le \|k-k_n\|_{L^1} < \epsilon$ and $K_n$ is compact. I think that's right.

Comment: @TrialAndError can you please explain how you bound $\|K\|$ with $k$'s $L^1$ norm (or $K_n$)...

Comment: $\int|\int k(s+t)f(s)ds|^2dt \le \int|\int \{|k(s+t)|^{1/2}|f(s)|\}|k(s+t)|^{1/2}ds|^2dt$. Now apply Cauchy-Schwarz in $s$.